# Working holiday in Europe for Singaporean passport holders

Tags: visas, schengen, working-holiday

(I'm asking this question on behalf of a friend.)

My friend wants to go travelling around Europe and she has a Singaporean passport. Now, Singaporean passport holders don't need a Schengen visa in advance (as far as I know) as long as their stay is less than 90 days. However, she also wanted to work during the trip (teaching / bartending, etc) to support herself during the trip. Is that allowed, or does it require a working holiday visa? If it does require a working holiday visa, is there a common one that (like the standard Schengen tourist/business visa) or must one be obtained individually from each country in the itinerary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in Europe (at least in France) you need specific visa to work, such as the Work & Holiday visa.

As for the possibility to travel and work in other Schengen countries while holding a Work & Holiday visa, it seems that it's not allowed, according to [this page](http://forum.pvtistes.net/vie-pratique/47833-voyage-en-europe-avec-un-pvt-france.html) (in French).

To be precise, Schengen countries offer more freedom to other Schengen countries' citizens only. For other people like your friend, you have to individually check each country's policies. But from what I imagine, your friend can get a Work & Holiday visa in one country and visit the rest (if Singaporean only need a passport to visit a country).

A good idea would then be to pick a country either where salary is good or a central country from which it is easy to travel around.